# what does "nullbyte" really do in php?

Tags: php

I know the null byte in PHP may result in some security problems, like LFI/RFI. I checked the manual and it says "As null bytes denote the end of a string in C, strings containing them won't be considered entirely but rather only until a null byte occurs". So I decided to test this by myself, but I encountered some issues.

I wrote a test code snippet, as follows:

```
<?php
    $a=$_GET['a'];
    echo $a;
    include $a.'.jpg';
    //include 'a.txt';
```

The filename of this script is "index1.php". I accessed this file through the url `http://localhost/Demo/index1.php?a=a.txt%00`. When I ran this script, it displays the following:

```
a.txt
( ! ) Warning: include(): Failed opening 'a.txt' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp\www\Demo\index1.php on line 4
```

The "a.txt" displayed corresponds to the "echo $a" in the script, but it couldn't include the "a.txt" file and instead displayed a warning. When I test the script after changing the code to `include "a.txt"`, the file "a.txt" is included correctly!

Why does this happen? I tested this on windows + wamp 3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NULL Byte vulnerability was fixed in php 5.3.4, you probably have a superior version of PHP.

See : http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php at section 5.3.4, in "security" :

> Paths with NULL in them (foo\0bar.txt) are now considered as invalid.
>   (Rasmus)

Comment: I use PHP 5.4.16.if the vulnerability was fixed,why it display the waring can not include "a.txt",is it should show can not include "a.txt.jpg'?

Comment: Because you could use yourself a null byte in your code, to have PHP including "a.txt" This says, I won't include "a.txt" because there is a null byte in the filename string. Note that null byte isn't a vulnerability, PHP handles it as such in order to prevent LFI attacks.

Comment: do you mean when I use "include $a.'.jpg';" ,it contains an nullbyte in the filename so it can not include the "a.txt’,but when I directly use include "a.txt",because there is no nullbyte in the filename,so it can include correctly?

Comment: when you try to include "a.txt%00.jpg" there it contains a null byte, and you cannot include "a.txt" this way (that's what php says to you).

Comment: I know what you mean!tanks very much!but can you tell me which doc explain this?